# Telegram sendPhoto with multipart/form-data not working?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Hi I am trying to send an image. The documentation states that I can send a file using multipart/form-data.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
// I checked it, there really is a file.
$file = File::get(Storage::disk('local')->path('test.jpeg')) // it's the same as file_get_contents();

// Here I use the longman/telegram-bot library.
$serverResponse = Request::sendPhoto([
    'chat_id' => $this->tg_user_chat_id,
    'photo' => $file
]);

// Here I use Guzzle because I thought that there might be an 
// error due to the longman/telegram-bot library.
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post("https://api.telegram.org/$telegram->botToken/sendPhoto", [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'photo',
            'contents' => $file
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'chat_id',
            'contents' => $this->tg_user_chat_id
        ]
    ]
]);

Log::info('_response', ['_' => $response->getBody()]);
Log::info(env('APP_URL') . "/storage/$url");
Log::info('response:', ['_' => $serverResponse->getResult()]);
Log::info('ok:', ['_' => $serverResponse->getOk()]);
Log::info('error_code:', ['_' => $serverResponse->getErrorCode()]);
Log::info('raw_data:', ['_' => $serverResponse->getRawData()]);
```

In both cases, I get this response:

```
{\"ok\":false,\"error_code\":400,\"description\":\"Bad Request: invalid file HTTP URL specified: Wrong URL host\"}
```

Other download methods (by ID and by link) work. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: The `multipart` isn't a valid key in the payload. Use `photo`

Comment: @0stone0 multipart is a key option for GuzzleHttp\Client->post() method.
https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [php-telegram-bot](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot)
 library, `sendPhoto` can be used like so:

```php
<?php

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram;
    use Longman\TelegramBot\Request;

    // File
    $file = Request::encodeFile('/tmp/image.jpeg');

    // Bot
    $key = '859163076:something';
    $telegram = new Telegram($key);

    // sendPhoto
    $chatId = 000001;
    $serverResponse = Request::sendPhoto([
        'chat_id' => $chatId,
        'photo' => $file
    ]);
```

---

The trick is to use `Request::encodeFile` to read the local image.

Comment: Thank you. I also found another solution. I used `fopen(Storage::disk('local')->path($url))` instead of `file_get_contents(Storage::disk('local')->path($url))` and that works too.